# Upgrading an existing iOS application in App Store from new sources

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I took over an existing iOS project from another company. My client can't give me access to his iTunes Connect because he updates app with Application Loader. I don't have access to provisioning profiles from previous developer.

So, I need to know which parts of my application must be similar to existing app, which I want to update. And what if I want update iOS version from 5 to 6?

Comment: You can't. You need him to transfer the app to you at the least. There is a unique bundle ID given to the app on iTunes connect. This is what needs to be the same... but it is globally unique.

Comment: More information on App Transfer: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/8.0.0.9.5.2.5.9.3.1.2.3.3.1.5.10.1

Comment: But what if i know Bundle Identifier? I have source codes from previous application and I see bundle id (com.xxxxx.zzzzz). What if my new application will have the same bundle id?

Comment: Not that one. It's a globally unique one created in iTunes connect. Not the one created in Xcode. Put it this way, if what you are trying to do was possible, what would stop me from updating the Facebook app with my own version?

Comment: Sorry, I asked unclear question. So, again. My client is owner of application (he has this app in his iTunes Connect). What I need to do is create production build, which I send him and he will make app update via Application Loader.
So my job is only make right build which he can update on his iTunes Connect account.

Comment: Oh!!!! I see :D In that case, make sure the bundle ID is the same. Two ways to do this. Either send him the code and get him to build and upload. Or he needs to add a provisioning profile to his iTunes Connect for you so that you can build him and send him the ipa so he can upload.